# Свойство записывается со второго раза

Tags: php, битрикс

Помогите разобраться! 
При обновлении элемента инфоблока Битрикс, по событию должно присваиваться значение. Если изначально поле значения пустое, то код не работает. Точнее срабатывает со второго раза. Нужно зайти в изменение элемента и нажать "сохранить" без изменения значения.

```
  <?php


    AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnAfterIBlockElementUpdate", Array("StartRatingUpdate", "Update"));

    class StartRatingUpdate
    {
        function Update(&$arFields)
        {
            if ($arFields['IBLOCK_ID'] == BOXER_IBLOCK_ID) {

                $db_props = CIBlockElement::GetProperty(
                    $arFields['IBLOCK_ID'],
                    $arFields['ID'],
                    ['sort' => 'asc'],
                    ['CODE' => 'ATT_BXREC_RT']
                );

                if ($ar_props = $db_props->Fetch()) {

                    $bxrecRatingVal = $arFields['PROPERTY_VALUES'][$ar_props["ID"]][$ar_props["PROPERTY_VALUE_ID"]]['VALUE'];


                    if (!empty($bxrecRatingVal)) {
                        $arFields['PROPERTY_VALUES'][$ar_props["ID"]][$ar_props["PROPERTY_VALUE_ID"]]['VALUE'] = 'HELLO!';


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Событие срабатывает после обновления элемента. Вы присваиваете новое значение переменной, но не сохраняете данные после этого. Или я не так понял вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?php


AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnAfterIBlockElementUpdate", Array("StartRatingUpdate", "Update"));

class StartRatingUpdate
{
    function Update(&$arFields)
    {
        if ($arFields['IBLOCK_ID'] == BOXER_IBLOCK_ID) {

            $db_props = CIBlockElement::GetProperty(
                $arFields['IBLOCK_ID'],
                $arFields['ID'],
                ['sort' => 'asc'],
                ['CODE' => 'ATT_BXREC_RT']
            );

            if ($ar_props = $db_props->Fetch()) {

                CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValueCode($arFields['ID'], "ATT_BXREC_RT", 'HELLO!');

            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Обратите внимание!** Вот [ссылка](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/setpropertyvalues.php) на мануал метода *SetPropertyValues*

В вашем случае использован кусок кода из Пример 2 (код вызова метода для свойства типа "Строка") т.е. это работает если свойство куда будет записываться значение имеет тип "Строка"

Comment: Всё тоже самое. Свойство типа "строка", всё верно. Дело даже не в записи значения в свойство. В моём случае, если смотреть логи, переменной $bxrecRatingVal значение "прилетает" только со второго раза. Т.е. в редактировании элемента в поле свойства было пусто, я вбил значение и нажал "сохранить", переменная осталась пустая. Зашел в элемент, нажал "Сохранить" и вот тогда в переменной появилось моё значение.